# Model View Controller example in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, model-view-controller

I am learning MVC in iOS. I am reading some of the articles in Google. I can understand what is MVC. But in many tutorial they are not mentioned any sample code based on MVC concept. Please give me any sample code or simple example Using MVC concept. Please explain me anybody how to work on model and view and controller based on coding part. I think this is helpful for so many people. Help me anybody. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey you could check out [this link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/46988/ios-design-patterns) will help you with understanding and applying of design pattern along with a demo.

Comment: You can go through the application https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: This article covers a handful of the design patterns you should be aware of: http://www.raywenderlich.com/46988/ios-design-patterns

Comment: I would suggest to re-think your question and ask your question in a different way. Because what you did ask, after I read your question again, is something you could have done alone : simply find everything you can on MVC and then loo up yourself what is really relevant and fitting your needs (of knowledge/code). Editing your question may give you points, in the end. Instead of being moderated!

Answer (score 4):

> **This goes for MCV as for learning iOS in general**

I would strongly suggest you to have a look in the **iOS developer library**. And specifically, check out their [Start developing iOS Apps Today](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/index.html) guide. This tutorial goes through some design patterns (**including MVC**).

It is a great start and you will see how the guys at Apple want you to write code for iOS.

It is a **full tutorial including the code** that you have to write, and **everything is explained**.

And there are other tutorials and sample codes for every framework, it is definitely a must read and something to check out all the time while coding for iOS. Just check out the whole [library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/).